# Pangram function in c++

Tags: c++, pangram

I am browsing for two days now and have not find a solution which meets to my solution.
I am trying to write a Pangram function. I have tried many ways but could not succeed.
My function IsPangram always give `it is not Pangram` suggest me some ways.

```
void isPangram()
{
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    char str[26];
    cout << "Enter a string to check if its Pangram or not: ";
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        cin >> str[i];

        if (i >= 97 && i <= 122) {

            cout << "It is Pangram" << endl;
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "it is not Pangram" << endl;
            break;
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    isPangram();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: When do you expect `i` to be set to greater than 97?

Comment: @– James Root This is the range of characters from a to z in ascii table. thats why i am trying it.

Comment: By the way, pangram is a noun, not an adjective, so it should be "check if it's a pangram", not "check if its Pangram".

Comment: Related: [Pangram in C using functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68200504) has some similar answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues in your code -

(i) You are trying to check if each character is a pangram, which is wrong.

(ii) For checking, you are checking against the index `i` instead of the character read which is `str[i]`.

(iii) This statement `if ( i >= 97 && i <= 122   )` will always evaluate to `false` since the value of `i` can be only between 0 and 26. Hence you are always getting not a pangram.

Try this -

```
void isPangram() {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    char str[27];
    cout << "Enter a string to check if its Pangram or not: ";

    // Read the string
    cin >> str;

    short flagArr[26]; // Array to flag the characters used
    memset(flagArr, 0, sizeof(flagArr));
    bool panGramFlag = true;

    // Loop through the string and mark the characters read
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
            flagArr[str[i]-'A'] = 1;
        }
    }

    // Loop through flag array and check if any character is not used.
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (flagArr[i] == 0) {
           panGramFlag = false;
           cout << "It is not Pangram" << endl;
           break;             
        }
    }   

    if (panGramFlag)
        cout << "it is Pangram" << endl;

}

int main() {

    isPangram();

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `flagArr[str[i]-'A'] = 1;` i could not understand this statement ? could you please explain it a little? @buchipper

Comment: @QasimAli Maybe you should start with a simpler program first and learn some basic C++.

Comment: @QasimAli - `str[i]` is the character that was entered by the user. The character `'A'` has the value of 65. If the character at `str[i]` is 'B', then `flagArr[str[i]-'A']` translates to `flagArr['B'-'A']` which is `flagArr[66-65]` which is `flagArr[1]`. Thus if `str[i]` is 'B', then `flagArr[1]` will be set to 1 - which means the sentence contains the character 'B'. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This only works for upper-case alphabetic characters, which is weird.  You could use `toupper`. Also, your program only has room to input a 26-byte string, so it can't read "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" or other standard examples. Your analysis of the bugs in the question look right, though.  (Your `flagArr` only needs to be `bool` or `char`, no point in using `short`.  And the input/output should be in `main`, passing a string to `isPangram`, otherwise not much point in making it a function.  You have an `int i;` at the top which is shadowed by the `for( int i ...` vars.)

Comment: Also, normally you'd loop while `str[i] != 0`, instead of always scanning all the bytes in your input buffer regardless of the length of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool chkpangram(string &str)
{
    int m[26] = {0}, i, index;
    for(i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90)
            index = str[i] - 65;
        else if(str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)
            index = str[i] - 97;

        m[index] = m[index]++;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<=25; i++)
        if (m[i] == 0)
            return (false);

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    string str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    if(str.length() < 26)
        cout<<"Not a Pangram";
    else
    {
        if(chkpangram(str) == true)
            cout<<"Is a Pangram";
        else
            cout<<"Not a Pangram";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As this can be an answer to the OP question, try to provide more context rather than just paste some code. Please refer to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) try to explain what was wrong and why, so other users with the same problem can understand your answer

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Always try to explain with your own words what your answer is about!

Comment: `m[index] = m[index]++;` looks like a bug, perhaps undefined behaviour in some revisions of C++.  You post-increment but then assign the unincremented value to the array.  Since you're checking for a pangram, `m[index] = 1;`, you don't need a count just a boolean.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple one, think logically

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
void isPangram()
{
    int i;
    char str[26];
    cout << "Enter a string to check if its Pangram or not: ";
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    cin >> str[i];

    if ((str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)||((str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 91))
    {

        cout << "It is Pangram" << endl;
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "it is not Pangram" << endl;
        break;
    }

    }
}

int main()
{
    isPangram();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//Optimal code using hashing

```
string str;
int i,h1[26]={0},flag=0;

for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    h1[str[i]-'a']++;
}
for(i=0;i<26;i++)
{
    if(h1[i]!=1){
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
}
flag==1?cout<<"No"<<endl:cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
```

}
//Hope it helps

Comment: `str` is a `char`, so how/why are you indexing it with `str[i]`? Did you mean it to be a `std::string`?

Comment: Sry for that..use string

Comment: This accesses outside the `h1` array if any input character isn't a lower-case ASCII letter.  Also, that ternary at the bottom is horrible.  `std::cout << flag ? "No\n" : "Yes\n";  Or just write a function that returns a bool.  Oh, also, this is checking for each alphabetic character appearing exactly one (h1[i] == 1), not for a pangram which only needs a bool array.